# R. Bott's lectures on characteristic classes

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

I am searching for R. Bott's lectures on characteristic classes and Gel'fand Fuks cohomology (New Mexico State Univ. 1973), apparently there are notes of these lectures taken by Mostow and Perchik which were published in some proceedings. But I was not able to find these proceedings.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: These notes were taken by L. Conlon: http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2FBFb0058509?LI=true Is this not what you are looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that what you are looking for is [here](https://math.ucr.edu/%7Eres/bott-nmsu/Bott%20-%20Lectures%20on%20Gelfand-Fuks%20Cohomology%20and%20Foliations.pdf)
which was noted by Mostow and Perchik.

Comment: Thank you so much!